# Prove that the Diophantine equation $ax+by=c$ has no integer solutions if $\gcd(a,b)$ does not divide $c$

Tags: diophantine-equations, divisibility

Prove that the Diophantine equation $ax+by=c$ has no integer solutions if $\gcd(a,b)$ does not divide $c$ there was a hint which is use use contradiction.

Comment: $2x+2y=1$ left side is even and right side is odd

Comment: $ax+by =  \gcd(a,b)[a'x+b'y] = c \\ $

which simply says that $\gcd(a,b) | c$

Answer (score 1):

If $d=gcd(a,b)$ then $d|a$ and $d|b$, whence $d|(ax+by)$, so it must be that $d|c$. Now take the contraposition.

Answer (score 1):

$$\gcd(a,b)\mid ax+by=c,$$
if there exists integral solution $(x,y)$.